# Adding text in loop python only once (adding a string to a column in a loop)

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to add a red ABCD on the left as it is on the top ... I have a big problem with it because everything is done in a loop

as I have now

[image: as I have now photo]

as I want to have

[image: as I want to have photo]

```
import sys
INF = sys.maxsize
def floydWarshall(graph):
    n = len(graph)
    dist = [[] for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            dist[i].append(graph[i][j])
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j])
    print('Najkrotszy dystans pomiedzy kazda para')
    print("\033[91m      A       B       C       D\033[0m")
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if dist[i][j] == INF:
                print("%7s" % ("INF"), end=' ')
            else:
                print("%7s" % (dist[i][j]), end=' ')
        print()
graph = [[0, 5, INF, 10] , [INF, 0, 3, INF], [2, INF, 0, 1], [5, 3, 4, 0]]
floydWarshall(graph)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could for example introduce a `row_names` list with the row names:

`row_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

Then right after the first for loop after the header print, use the index `i` to get the correct `row_name`:

```py
# ...
    for i in range(n):
        print("\033[91m{0}\033[0m".format(row_names[i]), end= ' ')
        for j in range(n):
# ...
```

If you are using Python >= 3.6 you could replace the format function with [F-Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
print(f"\033[91m{row_names[i]}\033[0m", end= ' ')
```

**EDIT:** or as @kosciej16 suggested, use `chr(ord("A") + i)` instead of `row_names`:

- `ord()` returns the ASCII code of the letter "A" (65)
- adds the index `i` to it
- and `chr()` then converts the ASCII number back to a character

(e.g. "B" would be `ord("A") + 1` = 66 -> `chr(66)` -> "B")

**Output:**

```py
Najkrotszy dystans pomiedzy kazda para
A       0       5       8       9 
B       5       0       3       4 
C       2       4       0       1 
D       5       3       4       0
```

Comment: instead of introducing row_names you could use `chr(ord("A") + i)`

Comment: Also, if you *are* using an array to get the row headers, you can just index into a string: `headers = "ABCD"` and then `headers[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things a great deal by doing something like this:

```
for i in range(n):
  row_header = chr(ord("A") + i)
  preformatted_values = ("INF" if v == INF else v for v in dist[i])
  formatted_values = [f"\033[91m{v}\033[0m" for v in preformatted_values]
  row = "/t".join(formatted_values)
  print(f"{row_header} {row}")
```

This doesn't handle all the formatting you're doing in the `row` string, but you can also use something like `format()` instead of `print()` in order to do that formatting on each element and then use the above-shown `join()` rather than iterating manually through your row.

Another alternative is to use one of the veteran libraries like [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/).